# "Dark mode" recently stopped working for me. How can I fix it?

Tags: settings, desktop

In `System Settings` > `Desktop` > `Appearance`, I have it set to switch to the dark style between sunset and sunrise. Normally, it works as expected. However, within the past few days it has stopped working.

All my software is up-to-date. Has there been a recent update to anything that would affect this?

I know sometimes resetting preferences by deleting config files can help. Is there anything I should try resetting?